# How do you set the number of decimal places of a value returned in a msgbox after doing a simple calculation in VBA excel 2010

Tags: vba, decimal-point, msgbox

im currently using a simple msgbox calc to return a calculated value. How can i restrict the number of decimal places shown in the returned value in the answer msgbox.

here is the script!

```
Sub CalcmsgboxHect()
    On Error Resume Next
    num = InputBox("Please Enter The Number Of Acres You Would Like To Calculate Into Hectares ")
    MsgBox num * 0.404686 & " Is the Number Of Hectares."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. This applies a format with two decimal places and a thousands separator:

EDIT: Wrapped in an IF to skip if num = 0.

```
Sub CalcmsgboxHect()
Dim num As Double

num = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Enter The Number Of Acres You Would Like To Calculate Into Hectares ", Type:=1)
If num <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Format(num * 0.404686, "#,##0.00") & " Is the Number Of Hectares."
End If
End Sub
```

As a bonus I declared `num` as a `Double` (depite your reckless moniker). Also, I used `Application.Inputbox`, which allow you to specify and input type. An input type of `1` means the user has to enter a number. This might allow you to get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` line.

Comment: This works however if you hit cancel it still appears an answer box with the answer 0 is the number!!! how can i force the answer box not to display when you hit the cancel key, Thanks.

Comment: Please see the edit. Please note that `Application.Inputbox` isn't the most robust control. If I remember right, there's no way to distinguish entering a zero from cancelling.

Comment: Many thanks, as soon as my rating is high e enough ill vote up! Thanks for the suggestion and tips on application inbox.